# Exchange 2003 default permissions for ANONYMOUS LOGON and Everyone

Tags: windows-server-2003, security, exchange-2003

ANONYMOUS LOGON and Everyone have the following top level permissions in our Exchange 2003 Server:

- Read
- Execute
- Read permissions
- List contents
- Read properties
- List objects
- Create public folder
- Create named properties in the
  information store

Are these the "default" settings?
In particular, are the "Read" and "Execute" permissions a problem?
We have a simple small business setup, Outlook clients connect to the server on the local network, OWA is used from outside the network for browser and smartphone access.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Those settings look correct.  Anonymous and everyone need permission to be able to read those objects and doesn't necessarily give them any access to data.

I believe exchange/ad best practices analyzer will identify large top level permissions issues such as these.